# How to get translations on Launchpad for a custom program

Tags: python, translation, pyqt

I wrote a program and uploaded it to a ppa. This program uses translations which I manually create using `pylupdate4 Translate.pro`, then Qt-Linguist, then `lrelease Translate.pro`on my home PC. So the translation process utilizes *ts-files and the binary *qm-files that my program is loading. However I only read about `mo`,`po`and such on Launchpad to translate something.

How can I get my *.ts-files on Launchpad so that people can translate them easily? 
Or am I on the wrong way?

My python program is loading the *.qm files with this code:

```
locale = QLocale()
LOCALNAME = str(locale.system().name())
lang=str.split(LOCALNAME,"_")[0] 
translator= QtCore.QTranslator()
translator.load(getParentDir()+"/Translate/main_%s"%lang)
self.app.installTranslator(translator)
```

I don't know if it can handle different files than *.qm.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Launchpad to help translate free software, both directly with upstream projects, (such as Limewire), and also as packages in distributions such as Ubuntu.

When you're deciding what to translate, think about the following:

Can you work on the upstream project, rather than the distribution package?
Do you know and understand the software well enough to know the context of the strings you need to translate?

Are you familiar with the [translation](https://vanantranslation.com) standards you'll need to stick to?
To learn about the processes and standards that a project applies to its translations, you should get in touch with the translation team that manages its localization into your language. Most projects work with a translation group - an umbrella organization of many teams - who look after translation quality control. Each translation group assigns teams to look after particular languages.

Reference site

https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/StartingToTranslate

Answer (score 0):

Rosseta, the launchpad translation service don't work with Qt files, it is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/68959).

You can use [ts2po](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220404/why-use-pip-over-easy-install) to convert from .ts to .po files and backwards, but it doesn't support all the new ts features.

Qt 4.5 comes with a tool, lconvert, that should be able to convert ts files to po and back, but documentation is lacking.